# Nagivate between buttons in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 buttons in an html and in a columnBox and i wish to navigate between buttons. I need to use up down right left  keys to nagivate between buttons and select them and then use enter key to finally make a choice.Can it be done through looping? Any other logics? I need to do it in java script. Any leads of doing it would really help..

[image]

Comment: Looping is for doing something repeatedly. You just need to create event listeners on each button that sets the focus on the next button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Here is an example to get you started: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/navigate-form-fields-with-arrow-keys.html

Before posting a question to StackOverflow, make sure you search for it online first.

Comment: i have attached an image to show how my html looks like. For now i have been able to just work with keys and get all buttons mapped on different keys only.

Comment: Thankyou Barmar and Ralph. I am sorry just a new bee here. Would definitely work on asking better questions. i had searched a lot on google but wasnt able to get what i wanted. Your link seems really helpful and i ll work on it surely. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by jquery as well

```js
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                var selected = 1;

                $("body").keydown(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
                        if (selected != 1) {
                            selected--;
                            var elem = "b" + selected;
                            $('.box').removeClass('active');
                            $('#' + elem).addClass('active');
                        }
                    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
                        if (selected != 4) {
                            selected++;
                            var elem = "b" + selected;
                            $('.box').removeClass('active');
                            $('#' + elem).addClass('active');
                        }
                    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
                        var href = $('.active').find('a').attr('href');
                        alert(href);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
            .box{
                padding: 5px;
                float: left;
                display: inline-block;
                border: solid 2px #444;
            }
            .active{
                background: #ffff66;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
            <li class="box active" id="b1"><a href="#b1">item 1</a></li>
            <li class="box" id="b2"><a href="#b2">item 2</a></li>
            <li class="box" id="b3"><a href="#b3">item 3</a></li>
            <li class="box" id="b4"><a href="#b4">item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress), here is an example

```js
var activeChoice = '';
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
 function activate(div){
   if(oldDiv = document.querySelector('.active')) {
     oldDiv.classList.remove('active');
    }
    document.querySelector('.' + div).classList.add('active');
    activeChoice = div;
    console.log(div)
  }
 switch (event.which || event.keyCode){
    case 13:
       alert(activeChoice);
        break;
     case 37:
       activate('left');
        break;
      case 38:
       activate('up');
        break;
      case 39:
       activate('right');
        break;
      case 40:
       activate('down');
        break;
      
   }
   console.log(event.keyCode)
    
    /*
     enter 13
      left 37
      up 38
      right 39
      down 40
    */
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  right
</div>
<div class="left">
  left
</div>
<div class="up">
  up
</div>
<div class="down">
  down
</div>
```